# Setting up a Firebase test database in Android

Tags: java, android, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am in a team that develops a web app and an android app using the same firebase database. I am using React. We need to find a way to create a secondary database for testing. In my case I can just swap the config files:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

export const config = {
    apiKey: "****",
    authDomain: "*****",
    databaseURL: "******",
    projectId: "******",
    storageBucket: "*******",
    messagingSenderId: "*******"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default firebase;
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Android Studio?

We need to generate a new JSON file for another database, but firebase doesn't allow using duplicated SHA-1 fingerprints which are required to link said app to firebase.

We do understand we could create a second app dedicated for testing, but this sounds like a workaround and a tedious solution.

Comment: you can use product flavours, and set a different config json for each flavours

Comment: The problem is we cannot generate a new json, since the previous SHA-1 fingerprint was used

Comment: aren't you using two different projects to have two different databases?

Comment: why don't you just make another node in the same project which is a copy of everything?

Comment: @GregorioPalamà I am using two different apps, which operate on the same database.

Comment: @JacobCelestine Is this a firebase function? Can you clarify the `node` part?

Comment: oh ok, I didn't catch that. using the same database, though, wouldn't allow you to create an other database for testing. Firebase allows you to have one database per project. That's why I was suggesting flavours: two different projects, with the same behaviour, but different config/data

Comment: I mean like all the data is currently under one  root node, right? Just duplicate that root node and you'll have two instances of the same data.

Comment: @GregorioPalamà will two flavors generate two different SHA-1 fingerprints?

Comment: @JacobCelestine is it done with code, or is there a built in function for copying nodes?

Comment: @AlexIronside you can generate two different debug keystore (I'm assuming you're talking about debug SHA-1 key, let me know if you're talking about release ones). One you have two debug keystores, you can use them in your flavours, one keystore per flavours, and get different SHA-1 fingerprints. Also, you'll use different packages for different flavours, so you'll have different PlayStore generated fingerprints too